# Why facebook keeps on showing 'YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE' when sharing my blogger post?

Tags: blogger, meta, blogspot

When I tries to share my blogger post on facebook via a page then facebook thumbnail always shows 'YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE' message like this :[image]

I have modified my meta content on blogger template as :

```
<meta content='Technology' name='description'/>
```

and searched for the phrase 'YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE' but I'd not found any however it keeps on showing the same message on thumbnail. How can I remove that phrase or modify it?

Any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't enabled search description for your blog posts yet. To enable search description login to your Blogger dashboard go to **Settings**>**Search preferences**. Under the Meta tags section, click the Edit button right next to the Description. Now click **Yes** and **Save changes**. Now write different search descriptions for your blog posts. To do that, open a post in Blogger post editor and then **Post settings**>**Search Description**. Write search description here and save the blog post.